# MacBook Pro freezing but mouse responsive

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, performance

I have a brand new MacBook Pro purchased from Amazon. I just set everything up and every few minutes while using Chrome or Firefox, the Mac freezes. Specifically, no application or icon is responsive but I can still move the mouse cursor. If it helps to know, closing the lid does not switch off the screen. The only way out is a hard power off.

Short of resetting the system back to factory settings and going to the stone age is there something I can do to diagnose this? Amazon has replaced my laptop in view of a screen blemish and damaged coating which was discovered.

Comment: I have this same problem